# What is the best way to watch and signal file changes to a node.js app?

Tags: node.js, debian

I periodically rsync code changes to my production server. I have the following cluster code that creates workers for my main app.

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
function startWorker() {
    var worker = cluster.fork();
    console.log('CLUSTER: Worker %d started', worker.id);
}

if(cluster.isMaster){
    require('os').cpus().forEach(function(){
        startWorker();
    });
    // log any workers that disconnect; if a worker disconnects, it
    // should then exit, so we'll wait for the exit event to spawn
    // a new worker to replace it
    cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker){
        console.log('CLUSTER: Worker %d disconnected from the cluster.',
        worker.id);
    });

    // when a worker dies (exits), create a worker to replace it
    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal){
        console.log('CLUSTER: Worker %d died with exit code %d (%s)',
        worker.id, code, signal);
        startWorker();
    });
} else {
    // start our app on worker; see meadowlark.js
    require('./app.js')();
}
```

[This article](https://jaxbot.me/articles/zero_downtime_nodejs_reloads_with_clusters_7_5_2013) shows how to listen to a signal (in the articles case SIGUSR2, to restart the workers). In a nutshell he does something like:

```
process.on("SIGUSR2", function() {
      //Code to disconnect workers, delete cache and restart workers
});
```

My questions is:
- Is SIGUSR2 the best way to signal to the process that it should reload the workers ? What if I want to send some additional information ?
- Who is sending the signal ? Is it some OS feature that you can set to watch a file or directory ? How do I do that ?

Note:
- I would rather use some OS level feature that is not related to node.js. For example, some posts suggest using node.js specific modules like "naught" etc, but I would rather not use "naught". :)

Answer (score 0):

The Linux kernel supports a file system notification subsystem called [`inotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). You can use it with nodejs: https://github.com/c4milo/node-inotify